# how to capture recource link using simplepie parser

Tags: xml-parsing, simplepie

Im new to RSS feed parsing and having a little trouble. How would I use simplepie to capture the following resource?

`<enc:enclosure resource="http://images.craigslist.org/00202_lQ0CCpDIPk0_300x300.jpg" type="image/jpeg"/>`

Answer (score 0):

You would use the [get_enclosures()](http://simplepie.org/wiki/reference/simplepie_item/get_enclosures) function.

```
$feed = new SimplePie();
$feed->set_feed_url('http://simplepie.org/blog/feed/');
$feed->init();
$feed->handle_content_type();

foreach ($feed->get_items() as $item)
{
    foreach ($item->get_enclosures() as $enclosure)
    {
        echo $enclosure->embed();
    }
}
```

Comment: Iv tried the code above with the url of "http://toledo.craigslist.org/tla/index.rss" but no output. Please comment.

Answer (score 0):

Previous responder doesn't realize how SimplePie works. You don't use the get_enclosures() because the XML is not formatted as `<enclosure>` ...

Instead you do it like this:

```
require( 'autoloader.php' );
$feed = new SimplePie();
$feed->set_feed_url('https://denver.craigslist.org/search/msa?format=rss&query=left%20handed%20%7C%20lefthanded%20%7C%20lefty');
$feed->init();
$feed->handle_content_type();

foreach ($feed->get_items() as $item) {

    $encs = $item->get_item_tags( 'http://purl.oclc.org/net/rss_2.0/enc#', 'enclosure' );

    if ( !isset( $encs ) )
        continue;

    foreach ( $encs as $enclosure){

        if ( !isset( $enclosure['attribs'] ) )
            continue;

        foreach ( $enclosure['attribs'] as $attr ) { 
            echo "\n" . $attr['resource'];
        }
    }
}
```